# Obtain expansion of \cref

Tags: cross-referencing, expansion, cleveref

Is it possible to save the expansion of `\cref` in a macro? My try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}
\label{sec}

\edef\temp{\expandafter\empty\cref{sec}}
\show\temp

\end{document}
```

fails with some obscure errors.

Comment: To give some background info: can you tell use what you are trying to do with the macro?

Comment: This can't work, but perhaps there are other methods. They might depend on the intended usage.

Comment: The main reason is that I have something like `\section{Comments on \cref{other_section}}` and I would like that the bookmark in the PDF is resolved to `Comments on Section 3`.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138950/36296

Comment: or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235516/cleveref-and-pdf-bookmark

Comment: And read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-does-xy-problem-mean

Comment: Neither `\cref` nor `\Cref` nor the starred versions are expandable, so `\edef\foo{\cref{sec}}` is useless

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to leave the first answer unmixed with a much shorter way I provide a second solution with the `\crtcref` and `\crtCref` macros from my `crossreftools` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a section}
\label{sec}

\edef\temp{\crtcref{sec}}

\edef\Temp{\crtCref{sec}}


Content of reference: \temp\ or \Temp
\end{document}
```

Note that `\cref` or `\Cref` are not expandable, whereas `\crtcref` and `\crtCref` are expandable, hyperlinked versions however are not.

[image]

Current version of `crossreftools` is 0.9 (being uploaded to CTAN today (2019/01/03), the `\crtcref` etc. macros are from v0.1 however, v.0.9 contains a small bug fix for `\crtcref` and `\crtCref`, reporting wrong reference numbers, v.0.8. an extra macro `'crtcrefcountervalue`.

Comment: Doesn't work really well with subsections for me. Whereas the `\Cref` was "Section 2.1.2", the `\crtCref` is "Section 2" (using `\crtnumber`also yields 2).

Comment: @Norswap: Oh my, there is another new version of `cleveref` apparently that was released one week after `crossreftools v.0.6` -- I will investigate and update accordingly. I am pretty sure that it worked previously!. Thanks for notifying me!

Comment: @Norswap: Ok, I found a small typo in `\crtcref` and `\crtCref`, using the wrong information. Please note, that `\cref` itself still reports `section` for subsection etc. references, as long as there is no proper `\crefname` etc. setup -- I've uploaded `crossreftools 0.7` to CTAN, it should be available soon there and on TeXLive/MikTeX

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction! Unfortunately, it still doesn't work after updating to 0.8. This time the section number(s) doesn't show at all. `\crtnumber` and `\crtrefcountervalue` both report "2" (should be "2.1.2" for at least one of those as I understand it).

Comment: @Norswap: That's a misunderstanding. `\crtcrefcountervalue` **must** report 2. It can't report `2.1.2.` because that is not a counter value.

Comment: There is no `\crtnumber` macro, but `\crtCref` is indeed wrong. I have to check again. I was pretty sure I fixed it.

Comment: @Norswap: Yes, there is a stupid `%` preventing the `\crtCref` outputting the reference number. I'll upload a new version.

Comment: @Norswap: This fix should help: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\crtCref}[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname r@#1@cref\endcsname\relax
  \crt@refundefined%
  \else
  \crtCrefnamebylabel{#1} \crtcrefreference{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother`

Comment: @Norswap: Version `0.9` uploaded to CTAN

Comment: Works like a charm with the new version 

Comment: This (and the other solution, as well as the `refcount` package) don't seem to work when the label was defined in a `\include` .tex file, unless the `\edef` is after the `\label`.

Answer (score 5):

Neither `\cref` nor `\cref*` nor their uppercase variants are expandable, so storing them in a macro with `\edef` will not work.

This is a by-pass solution.

1. `cleveref` stores labels with the `@cref` suffix, so `\label{sec}`generates the label names `sec` and `sec@cref`.
2. The label for `othersec` (see code below) is

   ```
   \newlabel{othersec@cref}{{[section][2][]2}{1}}
   ```

   where `{[section][2][]2}` is the relevant information about the counter type (`section` here, `[2]` stands for the section number which is `2` here and, however, I could not figure out the meaning of `[]2` yet.
3. `\getrefnumber` by `refcount` package extracts the content stored under the label name, which is more complicated in the case of `cleveref`, but using a 'splitter' macro named `\split@@internal` that leaves the content within the first `[]` only in the input stream, it is possible to extract the counter type, i.e. `section` here.
4. `cleveref` defines `\cref@section@name` and `\Cref@section@name` as macros that holds the singular name of `section` and `Section`, similarly for other counters, depending on the arguments to `\crefname` and `\Crefname`.

Please note the wrapping `{}` pair around the `cleveref` label -- it is possible to use this with `\split@internal` and `\split@@internal`.

The macros `\xcref` and `\Xcref` are not wrappers for `\cref` or `\Cref` but a bypass.

I have repeated the the section value in the output of `\xcref` and `\Xcref` with `\getrefnumber{#1}` where the usual label is evaluated.

The code for `\xcref` and `\Xcref` checks for the existence of the label name as well, in order to provide 'nothing' if the label has not been defined yet -- this is important for the first compilation run of a document or after deletion of the `.aux` file.

Please note: The approach here might fail when `\label` is used with an optional argument which has been introduced by `cleveref` -- I have not tested this yet.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\makeatletter
\def\split@@internal[#1][#2][#3]#4{#1}%

\def\split@internal#1{%
  \expandafter\split@@internal#1%
}




\newcommand{\Xcref}[1]{%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1@cref}{%
  }{%
    \csname Cref@\expandafter\split@internal\getrefnumber{#1@cref}@name\endcsname\ \getrefnumber{#1}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\xcref}[1]{%
  \IfRefUndefinedExpandable{#1@cref}{%
  }{%
    \csname cref@\expandafter\split@internal\getrefnumber{#1@cref}@name\endcsname\ \getrefnumber{#1}%
  }%
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\edef\tmp{\Xcref{othersec}}

\section{This is a section and is followed by \Xcref{othersec}}
\label{sec}

\section{Other section}\label{othersec}

or use \tmp




\end{document}
```

[image]