# hyperref warns when using cleveref in \section

Tags: theorems, cleveref

I encounter a small but annoying problem with the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{good}
    Cleveref is good
\end{thm}

\section{Proof of \Cref{good}}
    It is trivial.

\end{document}
```

The compiler (pdflatex) complains

> ```
> Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
> (hyperref)                removing `\@ifnextchar' on input line 13.
> ```

Also the PDF TOC shows `Proof of good` instead of `Proof Theorem 1`.
Is their any solution other than saying `\section{Proof of Theorem \ref{...}}`?
After all, the whole point of using `cleveref` is not to repeat the fact that `good` is a theorem.

PS1. I also want a solution for `amsart` or more general document classes.
(That is, the order of `\usepackage`s is more or less fixed)

PS2. Feel free to mark duplicate.
Although other MWEs I saw on this site are far from minimal.

Comment: The issue is that `cleveref`'s machinery is not expandable (`\@ifnextchar`, for example, isn't), so it can't be turned into a PDF string. The `crossreftools` package provides an expandable alternative. Possible duplicate? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/381513/134574

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I got an error complaining `Use of \refstepcounter@optarg doesn't match its definition` when I use `\crtCref`.

Comment: Indeed, after leaving the comment I went to try my suggestion (I should probably try _and then_ comment :-). This problem is because `cleveref` inserts some non-expandable `\MakeUppercase` in the reference to the theorem, and when `crossreftools` tries to use it in an expansion-only context, hell breaks loose. I'll investigate :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said in the comment, the issue is that `cleveref`'s machinery is not expandable (the `\@ifnextchar` that `hyperref` complains about, for example, isn't expandable), so it can't be turned into a PDF string.

The `crossreftools` package provides an expandable alternative for cross referencing commands. For `cleverref` you can replace `\cref` by `\crtcref` and `\Cref` by `\crtCref`.

However, as you noted in your comment, only using that breaks badly. The reason is that `cleverref` redefines some internals of the theorems and inserts some `\MakeUppercase` and `\MakeLowercase` (which aren't expandable). The issue boils down to the fact that these commands end up in the cross reference code, which is expected to contain only text. When `hyperref` tries to expand that, chaos ensues.

I tried to find a proper fix, but most of them led to a can of worms of code which would then be incompatible with everything. An easier way out, which preserves `cleveref`'s functionality and leaves the cross reference text expandable, is to use `expl3`'s case changing functions. I used `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd` to replace the two occurrences of `\MakeUppercase` and one of `\MakeLowercase` by `\text_uppercase:n` and `\text_uppercase:n`, respectively, from the commands `\@othm`, `\@xnthm`, and `\@ynthm`. After patching that, the expandability problem is no more :-)

The pdf:

> [image]

and the pdf bookmark file:

```
\BOOKMARK [1][-]{section.1}{Proof of Theorem 1}{}% 1
```

Code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}

\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

% This patch must be after loading cleverref and before defining a new theorem
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\clist_map_inline:nn { \@othm, \@xnthm, \@ynthm }
  {
    \patchcmd #1 { \MakeUppercase } { \text_uppercase:n } { } { \FAILED: }
    \patchcmd #1 { \MakeUppercase } { \text_uppercase:n } { } { \FAILED: }
    \patchcmd #1 { \MakeLowercase } { \text_lowercase:n } { } { \FAILED: }
  }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{good}
    Cleveref is good. expl3 is awesome :D
\end{thm}

\section{Proof of \crtCref{good}}
    It is trivial.

\end{document}
```