# Hide cleveref links in section title

Tags: hyperref, cleveref

I would like links to be coloured in general, but not the cleveref links in section titles.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

% The section to reference
\section{Section Title}\label{sec:A}

% Colour links in normal text, like this one
Reference to \cref{sec:A}.

% This colours the link even in the section title, which I don't want
\section{Reference to \Cref{sec:A}}

% This hides the link in normal text, so...
Reference to {\hypersetup{hidelinks}\cref{sec:A}}.

% ... this should do what I want, but doesn't work.
% \section{Reference to {\hypersetup{hidelinks}\Cref{sec:A}}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with commands in section titles is that they must either be expandable or robust. Both `\Cref` and `\hypersetup` are neither.

Since `\hypersetup` will change the setting only when typesetting text, it doesn't need to be expandable (and it's impossible to make it so). Thus you make it robust with:

```latex
\let\ORGhypersetup\hypersetup
\protected\def\hypersetup{\ORGhypersetup}
```

Now `\Cref` is different. It *could* be made robust, but then in the PDF bookmarks you would see `Reference to sec:A` which is not that good. You can, however, make it expandable when `hyperref` will set up the PDF bookmarks by loading the `crossreftools` package and doing:

```latex
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\hypersetup#1{}%
  \let\Cref\crtCref
  \let\cref\crtcref
}
```

(I also disabled `\hypersetup` or you would get `Reference to hidelinksSection 1` :).

Working code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{crossreftools}

\let\ORGhypersetup\hypersetup
\protected\def\hypersetup{\ORGhypersetup}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \def\hypersetup#1{}%
  \let\Cref\crtCref
  \let\cref\crtcref
}

\begin{document}

% The section to reference
\section{Section Title}\label{sec:A}

% Colour links in normal text, like this one
Reference to \cref{sec:A}.

% This colours the link even in the section title, which I don't want
\section{Reference to \Cref{sec:A}}

% This hides the link in normal text, so...
Reference to {\hypersetup{hidelinks}\cref{sec:A}}.

% ... this should do what I want, but doesn't work.
\section{Reference to {\hypersetup{hidelinks}\Cref{sec:A}}}

\end{document}
```

output:

> [image]

Comment: This answer solves also the [wrong pdf bookmarks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504968/automatic-texorpdfstring-for-ref-in-pdf-bookmarks-section-titles) that the code from the question would produce. (Only solving the color-problem would be much easier, but your solution is much better.)